# Can Someone Explain Briar Raleigh and Magneto's Interest in Her?

Tags: marvel, x-men, magneto

So, doing some Internet surfing the other day and came across an article entitled 'Marvel Reveals New Brotherhood of Evil Mutants'. In the article, it said that the recent X-Men Blue #34 ended with Magneto having formed a brand new Brotherhood. Now, most of these made a good deal of sense to me (Exodus, Toad, Marrow, etc.). However, it also said that there was a human character named Briar Raleigh who was joining the team. Can someone please explain who she is and why Magneto is interested in her enough to place her on the Brotherhood? I have already looked at her Marvel Wiki page and it gives very little info.

Comment: She seems quite powerful. She has psychic abilities and can resist psychic attacks. That would seem to make her quite useful against enemies with those sorts of powers...

Comment: So, you know about the character? Do you know enough to write an answer with some references for research?

Comment: Based on a very cursory search, I'm afraid. She appears in [these comic issues](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Briar_Raleigh_(Earth-616)/Appearances) if you feel like doing a bit of light reading and then self-answering

Answer (score 4):

She stalked him in the solo series (Magneto 2014) because she developed an attraction to him after he dropped a car on her leg during an unspecified rampage. She is a billionaire after her whole family died of unknown causes and left her everything. We know this because she spends some time complaining about how boring her perfect life always was.

I'm not sure why she made the Brotherhood, but I suspect it has to do with her resources and connections. She is practically a hobby private investigator, so she's pretty smart, and about as ethical as you need to pretend to be to get in Magneto's good graces. I doubt she'll be doing much fighting because of her leg brace, but maybe she'll be regent on the new asteroid M (there's a new asteroid M) while Magneto and co are on Earth fighting.

Comment: Not a bad answer, would be willing to accept if you could find some panels or issue references to back your answer. :)

Comment: https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Briar_Raleigh_(Earth-616) has more references.